# Sum all every 1st row if 3rd row is not empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyxUx.png

Is there a way to get the sum of every first row when the 3rd row is not empty?
I was going back and forth with SUMPRODUCT and SUMIFS but I really don't know much about excel.

All I have is `=SUMIF(B2:B13, 1, C2:C13)`
so far.

With the table I have as an example the result should be 180.

Any help is appreciated. Also, happy holidays!

Edit 1:

The criteria for the sum isn't exactly the 1st rows but based on the value of the B column, namely 1, 2, and 3. The value should be 1, which I achieved with `=SUMIF(B2:B13, 1, C2:C13)`. The 2nd criteria being that B column should have the value of 3 and C column not being empty.

Edit 2:
So I got this from reading Scott's answer `=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B12 = 1) * (B3:B14 = 3) * (C3:C14 > 0) * (C1:C12))` but there must be a more elegant approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use same size but offset ranges:

```
=SUMIF(C4:C13,">0",C2:C11)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not getting the result I wanted with this.

Comment: Thanks for this, I found a temporary formula based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula for doing the same
    =SUMIF(A3:N3,"<>",A1:N1)